# write the var_dump($result); to the textfile

Tags: php

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');

fwrite($fh, $contact_first_name);         



$result = user_profile_xml($data);

echo '<br>begin response:<br>';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
echo'<br>end response<br>';
```

I want to write the var_dump($result); to the textfile

Comment: And read the manual page for that function it contains your answer (if that hasn't changed in the last X years): http://php.net/var_dump

Answer (score 1):

var_dump doesn't return anything so you can't put it in another variable.

Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php instead!

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP5:
        class x {
           ...
        }

```
    $obj = new x();

    ob_start();              // open data buffer for echoed data
    var_dump($obj); 
    $var = ob_get_clean();   // return "echoed" data and free buffer
```